# Enable button when edit text and checkbox are are fill and vice versa

Tags: java, android

Basically, I want to enable the button when both edit text and checkbox are fill
if any one of not fill then disable the button  in android with java

Answer (score 0):

you can add the condition inside setOnClickListener function i.e

```
button.setOnClickListener {
 if(editText.text.toString().isEmpty() || !checkBox.isChecked) return
 // do your job here...
}
```

Comment: without clicking on the button both edit text and checkbox are disabled...

Answer (score 0):

you can try do it like following:

check for editText if its empty and if the checkbox is checked,
so if editText isn't empty and checkbox is checked that will mean button shall be enabled,else disabled
and apply same condition for on checkbox listener

condition will look as follows

```
yourButton.setEnabled(yourCheckBox.isChecked() && !editText.text.toString().isEmpty())
```

example on text watcher implementation:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  yourButton.setEnabled(yourCheckBox.isChecked() && !editText.text.toString().isEmpty())
}
});
```

the reason you will need this on checkbox and on textwatcher at same time, is cause textwatcher can tell when editText is changed in realtime, on other hand the checkbox as far as I know it ain't possible thats why you will need the other condition set on checkbox click listener as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the above answer is not working.
even both edit text and checkbox are empty still the button is not disabled